# Unexpected syntax error during macro expansion

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am obtaining the below error while trying to use conditional compilation as below:
Note : Please note that ONE, TWO and THREE are pre-processor defined symbols whereas THREE is a macro and compiler used is IAR (IDE AtmelStudio)

1. Added additional brackets for ( (defined(ONE)) and likely for TWO and THREE
2. Tried to include an #else block with just a ) and putting the additional ) at the end of statement under #if (SUM)

```
#if (defined(ONE) && !defined(TWO)
      #if (SUM)
         && !defined(THREE)   
      #endif
         )
    some_statements_1
    #else
    some_statements_2
    #endif /* #if (defined(ONE) && !defined(TWO) */
```

I expect the `some_statements_1` to be executed only if `ONE` is defined `TWO` is not defined and
**case 1:** if `SUM` is set > 0 then `THREE` shouldn't be defined
**case 2:** if `SUM` is set to 0 then as usual (no check for `THREE`)

Actual result is :

```
Pe018: expected a ")" at line 1 and
error: Pe169: expected a declaration at line 3
```

Comment: Macros don't cross line boundaries.  Long macros can use '\' to combine multiple lines into one.

Comment: I already tried inserting \ at the end of each line except the last, but the only result was the (same) syntax error was showing at the line 2 rather than line 1

Comment: What are `ONE`, `TWO`, and `THREE` defined as?

Comment: Is `SUM` a macro or a runtime variable?  If it's runtime, then this won't work at all.  Do you need to make the decision at compile time or run time?

Answer (score 2):

Expressions on pre-processor conditional lines need to be self-contained. You cannot put `#if` in the middle of a pre-processor expression.

Try:

```
#if defined(ONE) && !defined(TWO) && !((SUM) && defined(THREE))
     some_statements_1
#else
     some_statements_2
#endif
```

I am assuming `SUM` is a macro which expands to an integer constant expression suitable for evaluation by the pre-processor.

(EDITED: Was `#if defined(ONE) && !defined(TWO) && (!(SUM) || defined(THREE))`

Comment: I am not sure about the statement that #if can't be put in the middle of the pre-processor expression as I have done it previously. And regarding the sample code you provided, I agree that logically the code which you provided shoud be correct, but my requirement is like the SUM is just like a flag which can be externally disabled using some other mechanism. So my actual intention is if flag is set then add one more condition to execute the statements or else don't.

Comment: @user7083883 What sort of flag is `SUM` supposed to be? When you say "externally disabled", do you mean disabled at compile-time or disabled at run-time?

Comment: ok, SUM is an autogenerated macro based upon an XML file. A naive user can enable/disable a flag by editing the xml which will define the FLAG to 1/0 in the autogenerated header file (before compilation)

Comment: @user7083883 Okay, that sounds like a valid pre-processor constant. So what do you think is wrong with my code?

Comment: @user7083883 Also, I repeat that you cannot put `#if` in the middle of a pre-processor expression. Prove me wrong. (By "pre-processor expression" I mean some constant expression that is legal in an `#if` or `#elif` directive.)

Comment: My understanding is, since macro's are textual replacements, we are able to do it. But to add, I use this rarely, but it works for me all the time..

Comment: @user7083883 For example?

Comment: @user7083883: Clearly it does not work for you all the time: it doesn't work for you in this specific context.  It is not clear in what context it might work; it won't work in any normal C compilation.  You can't generate preprocessor statements.  Without backslashes, if the condition on the first `#if` line is self-contained, then the second `#if` and its `#endif` would be OK, but the code generated is improbable (not necessarily wrong, but likely to be wrong, if `SUM` is non-zero).  That would work, but it isn't what you've got in your code.

Comment: @Ian Abbott, I am afraid that your proposed solution has problems when both the user flag (SUM) as well as THREE is enabled/set. In this case our actual intention is NOT to execute some_statements_1.

Comment: @user7083883 The basic principle stands and I have edited the expression in my answer to match the textual description of the logic in your question, rather than trying to interpret the logic of your faulty code.

Comment: I stand corrected about the #if can be put in the middle of the pre-processor expression as its not working for my fresh attempts to do so. Also , the modified  logic mentioned above should serve the purpose  as far as I understand. Thanks all again..!

Answer (score -1):

if (defined(ONE) && !defined(TWO)

In the above statement, you missed one closing bracket. Please add it

Comment: this is correct but you should point him to the missing line break as he evidently has it there but on another line